# How to append dataframe index by union an array in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

## Example

df:

```
   col_a  col_b 
a   2      3
b   4      4
c   3      2

array: np.array([c,d,e])
```

## Expected

The array unions the dataframe index, it returns the dataframe as follow:

```
   col_a  col_b 
a   2      3
b   4      4
c   3      2
d   NaN    NaN
e   NaN    NaN
```

## Try

I use `pd.concat([pd.Series(array),df],axis=1)`,but failed. How can I get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `pd.concat`, one alternative way is to use [`DataFrame.combine_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html):

```
a = np.array(['c', 'd', 'e'])
df = df.combine_first(pd.DataFrame(index=a))
```

---

```
# print(df)

   col_a  col_b
a    2.0    3.0
b    4.0    4.0
c    3.0    2.0
d    NaN    NaN
e    NaN    NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`pd.Index.union`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.union.html) with [`df.reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html)

```
a = np.array(['c', 'd', 'e'])
df.reindex(df.index.union(a),axis=0)
   col_a  col_b
a    2.0    3.0
b    4.0    4.0
c    3.0    2.0
d    NaN    NaN
e    NaN    NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`numpy.union1d`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.union1d.html) like

```
idx = np.array(['c','d','e'])

df = df.reindex(np.union1d(df.index, idx))
df
   col_a  col_b
a    2.0    3.0
b    4.0    4.0
c    3.0    2.0
d    NaN    NaN
e    NaN    NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering the sample data:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'col_a': [2,4,3], 'col_b': [3,4,2]}
index = ['a', 'b', 'c']
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index)
```

This piece of code does what you need:

```
df = df.append(pd.Series(name='d'))
df = df.append(pd.Series(name='e'))
```

With the following output:

```
df
a   2.0     3.0
b   4.0     4.0
c   3.0     2.0
d   NaN     NaN
e   NaN     NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

One more way to do that:

```
a = np.array(["c","d","e"])

df.reindex(set(df.index).union(a)).sort_index()
```

The result is:

```
   col_a  col_b
a    2.0    3.0
b    4.0    4.0
c    3.0    2.0
d    NaN    NaN
e    NaN    NaN
```